# Gradle Artifact depedency - Artifactory artifact - How to find the path

Tags: path, find, gradle, artifactory, resolve

Building a Java/Groovy project, various tasks like compileJava, compileGroovy, test, etc requires various jar artifacts which Gradle provides them if you have properly defined what you need for each area of that task.

I'm making those available to the build script (build.gradle) and everything is working fine.

One of my other project that I'm working on, requires not only jar rtifacts but also an .xml file as an artifact for doing JIBX / XSLT transformation/processing.

My simple question:
- Gradle build process know how to fetch artifacts from Artifactory (as I have mentioned those Artifactory repositories in init.d/common.gradle file) and during the build it feeds the compile/test etc tasks with those jars, now if I have this .xml artifact uploaded to Artifactory as well, then:

a. How can I get the .xml artifact available to me in build.gradle so that I can perform some operation on it; for ex: Copy that .xml file to a x/y/z folder in a resultant project's jar/war file. Those jar files I can access via **project.configurations.compile.each or .find** or something like that but I'm not sure if I can access the .xml file the same way. The following code works fine for unjaring a jar file in build/tmpJibx/ folder i.e. if I need httpunit-1.1.1.jar during my build, then the following function when called, will create/unjar this jar in build/tmpJibx/httpunit folder.

```
// Unpack jar
def unpackJarItem( jarName ) {
   println 'unpacking: ' + jarName
   def dirName = "$buildDir/tmpJibx/$jarName"
   new File( dirName ).mkdirs()
   project.configurations.compile.find {
      def nameJar = it.name
      def iPos = nameJar.lastIndexOf( '-' )
      if( iPos > 0 ) {
         nameJar = nameJar.substring( 0, iPos )
         if( nameJar == jarName ) {
            def srcJar = it.toString()
            ant {
               unjar( src: "$srcJar", dest: "$dirName" )
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Gradle maintains artifacts in its cache at user's ~(home directory inside ~/.gradle) or C:\Users\.gradle under ...\caches..\artifactory..\filestore.........*

All Im trying to achieve is:
If I can do something like below:

```
copy {
      into "build/war/WEB-INF/conf"
      from "......<THIS_PATH_IS_WHAT_Im_LOOKING_FOR>:
      include "thatxmlartifactfile.xml"
}
```

I tried defining the entry under dependencies { ... } section, like below, but I'm not sure if Gradle will automatically have access to it somehow as Gradle is so great.

```
dependencies {
   compile 'groupid:artifactid:x.x.x'
   compile group: 'xxxx', artifac...: 'yyyy', version: 'x.x.x'
   //for ex:
   compile 'httpunit:httpunit:1.1.1'

   jibxAnt 'groupidnameofxmlfile:artifactidnameofxmlfile:versionnumberofxml@xml"
   ...

   ...
   ....

}
```

It seems like I have to first copy that .xml from where ever Gradle know it's available to some location n then from that location to my target folder.

```
   // Add libraries for acceptance tests
   project.configurations.acceptanceTestCompile.each { File f ->
      if( f.isFile() ) {
         def nameJar = f.getName()
         def jarName = f.getName()
         def fileInc = true
         def iPos = nameJar.lastIndexOf( '-' )
         if( iPos > -1 ) {
            jarName = nameJar.substring( 0, iPos )

            // Here I can say that one of the file/entry will be that .xml file
            // Now I have that in jarName variable and I can play with it, right?
            // i.e. if jarName == name of that xml file, then 
            copy {
                  into "some/folder/location"
                  from jarName
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to commit the XML file to source control. If you put it under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/conf/thatxmlartifactfile.xml`, it will get included in the War automatically.

If you need to get the file from Artifactory, you can do so as follows:

```
configurations {
    jibx
}

dependencies {
    jibx "some.group:someArtifact:1.0@xml"

war {
    from { configurations.jibx.singleFile }
}
```

PS: It's often possible, and also preferable, to add files directly to the final archive, rather than going through intermediate copy steps.

Comment: I agree Pete and that's the answer there - long term for me. We are planning to include that .xml in the project's jar file so that once that jar is unjared then, I can get it via from "build/tmpJibx/jarfolder/conf" and include "file.xml". But at the same time, I was curious as we have lots of project's jar are consumed by other projects and they also generates such .xml/etc files which are consumed as well. Long term solution will be in to include all such files in the .jar and there we have it, when we need it. I also try what you said. Do you agree with my last update (post's bottom code)

Comment: Your code is overly complicated. See my answer for a much simpler solution.

Comment: agree, but i was using it for other purposes i.e. takes care of all .xxx artifacts as well. but the one you mentioned for .xml makes sense to me. thanks Pete.

Comment: Hey Pete, what's singleFile. You mean I have to use thatxmlartifactfile in place of singleFile keyword you mentioned within the war task inside from section ?

Comment: You should use the code as-is. This is calling `Configuration#getSingleFile`. See the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) for details.

Comment: I'm getting this error: * What went wrong: 
Execution failed for task ':compileJibx'. 
> Expected configuration ':jibx' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains 50 files.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't use a dedicated configuration then. If you just add a single dependency of the form `@xml`, you should get a single file.